# Dynamically adding CSS cuts down page weight?

Tags: asp.net

Ok, this is bizaare and the only shop I've seen do this..granted we only have 2 developers in this shop.  My boss thinks that adding css files individually to pages using a helper method makes our site more efficient because when adding the style references in the Masterpage, then every page gets those styles making the site load slower.

So we have a company.css which is our main styles for stuff that is global like the main buckets such as header, footer, main, etc.

Then he wants me to go into each code-behind of lets say a certain set of pages for one of our features and use a utility method we created to dynamically add the product-related style sheet to those pages.  So for instance lets say we have a Reviews & Ratings feature.  We put all our reviews & ratings related classes and ids in Reviews.css.  Ok great.

So for instance in the .aspx.cs pages Init, we'd put this:

```
Util.AddStylesheet("Ratings.css");
```

Now he wants me to include that stylesheet in the codebehind of those pages where our reviews code touches in .aspx pages.  But says do not put a reference to Reviews.css in the master page.

Am I the only one who questions this method and says what's the point of having a master page then?  I mean really, if you put all your .css references in your master page does the argument of saying that now all pages have all these styles (some not used because they do not relate to that page) add weight to your load time for end users?

I mean common right?  Maybe people do this but I've never seen it and it's a management nightmare cause you have references all over the fing place dynamically adding certain .css pages to subsets of .aspx pages.

To me, even though we are an e-commerce site that receives 1 million hits a month, please, I mean seriously adding stylesheets manually and bypassing just putting them all in a master page just boggles my mind.  Am I the only one who thinks this is nuts and questions his assumption that doing that would make page weight excessive because they would be inheriting all stylesheets, some which would be wasted .css because it doesn't necessarily relate to that particular page?  For me, adding them to the master page is a done deal...simple, maintainable, and who cares.

I can understand page weight with JS, but .css?

Comment: Depending on how large your stylesheets are, this might make sense. After all, it does take time to parse the CSS. And as Joel Coehoorn notes, if you have separate CSS files you're making lots of requests to the server, which are also expensive. The only real way to know is to measure it ... and maybe measure a CSS minifier along the way.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually want to do is minimize the number of total http requests made, as well as the total bandwidth used.  If you have your reviews.css file linked from the master page, you need an extra http request for every page on your site, whether not you ever use the styles.  So in that sense, your boss is right.  Don't put this on the master page if it won't be used from all or most of your pages.

That said, I wouldn't have anything in the code-behind for this either, but rather a user control you can put on the required pages to render a style section or link.

Comment: In general, I agree with this.  If you can do dynamic inclusion it's probably better to do it with an actual style tag instead of via js.  But here's a question.  Even if you're including another style tag dynamically, it's still another request right?  And if it goes in the head of the page, it will slow the load time regardless.  The javascript allows the loading to be asynchronous, so the page can finish loading whether the additional css has finished loading or not.

Comment: @Marco: The problem there is that it fails the progressive enhancement check.  If javascript is disabled, you don't get the style at all. For many that might not be a problem, but then again it might. The nice thing about the user control approach is that it lets you abstract this part into what is essentially a separate transport layer; just have a base control all your other style sheet controls inherit from. That said, the OP's code-behind Util accomplishes much the same thing. Personally, though, I try to keep presentation code in the markup, and hence prefer the user control.

Answer (score 2):

I actually do *do* the compromise fairly often.

Most pages in my sites use all the standard css files declared in the masterpage but there's the odd one page here and there that use a special stylesheet. A high resolution view, a print view or maybe a jquery lighbox/gallery type control.

My ad-hoc stylesheet loading code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static void AddStyleSheet(this Page page, String Href)
        {
            PageExtensions.AddStyleSheet(page, Href, "all");
        }

        public static void AddStyleSheet(this Page page, String Href, String Media)
        {
            Href = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(Href);

            if (!PageExtensions.StyleSheetAlreadyExists(page, Href))
            {
                HtmlLink htmlLink = new HtmlLink();
                htmlLink.Href = Href;
                htmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                htmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                htmlLink.Attributes.Add("media", Media);

                page.Header.Controls.Add(htmlLink);
            }
        }

        static private bool StyleSheetAlreadyExists(Page page, String Href)
        {
            var preExisting = from Control c in page.Header.Controls
                              where c is HtmlLink && ((HtmlLink)c).Attributes["Href"] == Href
                              select c;

            return preExisting.Any();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, by default CSS files are being CACHED in the browser, so CSS will be loaded only ONCE anyway.

From my experience more seperate CSS files == more duplicated rules == bigger mess.

If you want to save up bit of bandwidth make sure you compress your CSS when writing it, so instead of:

```
#review 
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    margin-right:35px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url(images/blah.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

You write:

```
#review{margin:10px 35px 12px 12px;background:#fff url(images/blah.png) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about suggesting a compromise?

One master page with the most-commonly used elements defined (headers, links, navigation lists, etc) and then a location-specific stylesheet, ie `catalogue.css`, for such pages as need those styles. So the css is still able to be cached, but isn't forced on everyone that just visits the about-us page.

It's not ideal, but if the goal is to reduce the bandwidth of a single monolithic css file, it might get you some headway.

As it is, my personal approach is always to use the monolithic stylesheet; though having thought about it I'm tempted to try the suggested approach. It should work? Maybe... =/

Comment: that's how we're doing it.  Good .css maintenance means you break out .css per function reguardless of reason.  You don't put all your .css into one file..that's a maintenance headache.  I can't imagine anyone not seperating out their styles into seperate .css by function on the site.  It's just a mess if you don't maintenance-wise reguardless of how clean and how well your UI patterns are with the .css classes, always seperate out into a seperate .css if there are a decent amount of custom classes for the specific business feature/function

Comment: I must confess that, after posting my answer, I re-read your question and thought 'ah, is that what I just suggested...oops.' And then, somewhere, forgot to remove my answer. Ugh. I'm not Denny Crane, but can I claim mad cow anyway? =)